# jquery 1.4.2.min.js and jquery 1.11.0.js conflicting when used together

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use following jqueries but both when used together in any order are conflicting..I have tried to use also current latest versions of both but still the issue persists.My code looks something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: Don't use multiple versions of jQuery together. 1.4.2 is absolutely ancient - over 8 years old in fact. If you need to stay on the 1.x branch (for legacy IE support) I'd suggest upgrading to 1.12 at least. Then if you still have problems please post a specific error along with the code that creates it.

Comment: `var jQuery_1_4_2 = $.noConflict(true);`

`var jQuery_1_11_0 = $.noConflict(true);`

In the place of `$` you have to use variable of above as per requirement

Comment: Use neither - they are so out of date!